# Highcharts column range overlapping columns

Tags: highcharts

[image: columnrange]

From the picture above you can see the problem with overlapping columns.

I've tried with groupPadding but it does seem to work.

I prepared a jsffidle http://jsfiddle.net/cr1t/r7yyN/

```
Any Ideas?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `pointWidth`, then `groupPadding` is omitted. Remove `pointWidth` and you will get proper result: http://jsfiddle.net/r7yyN/1/

Also, you have different `groupPadding` for series, which may cause overlaping.

Comment: Eeck that is not the look I'm trying to go for ;)

Comment: I understand, I just explain that you can use or `pointWidth` or `groupPadding`.

Comment: Ah yes I see now what you meant. The answer I got over at the forum was to use point placement http://jsfiddle.net/r7yyN/5/ :)

Comment: If you said here that you have always three bars, I would answer here the same. You know, Pawel Fus on forum and Pawel Fus here is the same parson - me ;)