# How to show overlapping in various columns of highcharts column range graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, overlapping

I have a requirement to display an event based calendar. However, there are almost no functionalities related to calendar and its just a graphical representation of events throughout a year. Hence I have planned to use HighCharts `columnrange` graph. This saves me a lot of boilerplate for event listening.

However, when I get several overlapping events, its hard for me to show them as distinct.

How can I use highcharts existing features to accomplish this.

I have looked for style properties in events. But couldn't found anything helpful.
I tried searching if highcharts provides any form of gradient's implementation, but I didn't get much help there either.
I tried giving color with an opacity as `rgb(r,g,b, 0.2)` but somehow this gets turn to black.

Here is my working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ay1Lk2yw/2/). In this chart event8 and event7 are overlapping. There exact time duration is similar to event 9 and event 10 respectively.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387902/highcharts-column-range-overlapping-columns), but this question talks of vertical overlapping while I need to distinguish horizontal overlapping (as shown in demo). Also I tried the answer given here, which had no affect.

Can someone suggest the way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that good idea is to use partially-transparent colors for your columns. To use transparent colors you should use rgba, not rgb parameter.

Here you can find code that may help you:

```
  data: [{
    name: 'event7',
    x: 1,
    low: 36,
    high: 43,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    name: 'event8',
    x: 1,
    low: 25,
    high: 38,
    color: "rgba(100,100,100,0.6)"
  }]
```

And here you can find live example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ay1Lk2yw/4/

Comment: Absolutely..silly on my end to use rgb. I think I can live with this solution for now. However would appreciate a highchart method ( in case there exists one)

Comment: If you know that your columns will overlap, maybe you can move them a little bit? See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ay1Lk2yw/5/

Comment: I thought of this already. However, the height level of each event has a meaning and hence can't be displaced vertically. Also this might get clumsy with multiple overlaps around  a particular point